# Bit-flipping operations in T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, bit-manipulation

I have a bitmasked int field in my database. Usually I manage it through C# code, but now I need to flip a bit in the mask using T-SQL

How do I accomplish the following:

> The bit I want to flip: 1 << 8 (256)
>
> The mask value before I flip: 143
>
> The mask value after I flip: 399

This can be done without the bit operators that's missing in T-SQL, right?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Use XOR:

```
SELECT value ^ 256
```

So in your case, `SELECT 143 ^ 256` will indeed return 399. If you want to pass in the exponent as well:

```
SELECT value ^ POWER(2, power)
```

Comment: thanks! It solved my problem! Is there also a way to turn on the bit in an elegant way? (i already did it, but it looks ugly...)

Comment: Are you looking to flip or turn on? Flip - use XOR (^); turn on - use OR (|). If you want more elegance, wrap in a tersely named user-defined function. :)

Answer (score 20):

TSql Bitwise operators can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176122.aspx) and good article on how to use them is [here](http://sqlfool.com/2009/02/bitwise-operations/)

Comment: The question is about bit shifting, the articles you posted have nothing to do with that

Comment: The question is about bit-FLIPPING, not about bit shifting.

Comment: The title is wrongly about bit shifting, but the actual question about bit flipping.